# In R Shiny: Let plot disappear

Tags: r, shiny

This seems like a simple task, but I cannot find a solution. I want the plot only to appear when I select "plot". Otherwise, it shall disappear completely (no white space, "hello" should be moved up).

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("darkly"),
  selectInput("select", "select", c("No plot", "Plot")),
  plotOutput("plot"),
  tags$h1("hello")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
      if (input$select == "No plot") {
        NULL
      } else {
        plot(1)
      }
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `conditionalPanel` for this:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select", "select", c("No plot", "Plot")),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.select == 'Plot'", plotOutput("plot")),
  tags$h1("hello")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When using a `conditionalPanel` in this case you should drop the dependency to `input$select` in `renderPlot`. Otherwise you compromise `conditionalPanel`'s advantage of not re-rendering the plot. I edited your answer accordingly.

Comment: @ismirsehregal: Thanks for spotting and editing this. I just copy / pasted the code, but you're totally correct in that the `input$select` is ineffecient in renderPlot.